# jQuery not reading correct HTML attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, imagemap

I'm using a responsive image map jQuery plugin. On page load and on window resize, I'm reading the coordinate values of the responsive image maps and overlaying an  on top that scales with each image map.

This works fine on window resize, but on page load I'm having a problem reading the correct coordinate values.

I'm extracting the values like:

```
var test = jQuery('#imagemap').children('area')[i];
console.log(test);
```

The console will output: `<area id="area0" shape="rect" coords="0,0,32,32">`

But when I run: `console.log(test.coords);` to extract the "0,0,32,32" coords, I get:

```
0,0,40,40
```

`0,0,40,40` is the default coord position before the response image map plugin scales it down.

Why is there a conflict of values?

Comment: The expression `test.coords` has nothing to do with jQuery. *edit* - oh I see

Comment: Have you tried looking at the coords attribute vs the coords property? Usually you do want the property, but maybe said plugin is only updating the attribute and the property isn't automatically being updated.

Comment: ^^^ `test.getAttribute('coords')`

Comment: $(test).attr('coords'); the another value must be a property of your plugin or some property you had create but not an attribute of the html tag

Answer (score 0):

I would try doing it as pure jQuery (the jQuery way I suppose) and seeing how it works.

```
jQuery('#imagemap').children('area').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('coords'));
});
```

Incase you're not familiar this code loops through "each" of the area items and outputs the coords attribute. This is instead of using a for loop (or whatever you're currently doing)

OR if you wanted to stay with your method you could use eq(i) instead of [i] and the .attr method to keep it all jQuery... like this:

```
var test = jQuery('#imagemap').children('area').eq(i);
console.log(test.attr('coords'));
```